# Force the padding inside a C struct

Tags: c, struct, padding

I wonder if there is the way to force the padding of field of a C struct. 
I will try to explain it better with an example:
if i have the following structure:

```
struct foo{
    int32 a,
    int16 b,
    int8 c,
    int32 d,
    int32 e
};
```

I would to map it in the following way (considering the 0x00 as the starting address:

```
&foo.a = 0x00
&foo.b = 0x08
&foo.c = 0x0A
&foo.d = 0x10
&foo.e = 0x18
```

so that the fields are packed in 4 bytes each 8 bytes.

I obviously know that I can insert "padding fields", but is this the unique solution?

Comment: Which compiler? For GCC, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) for `aligned` attribute

Comment: For what purpose? You can use several attributes to control alignment and padding in gcc, but if you don't take care of what you are doing, you could easily force gcc to produce annoyingly slow and ineffective code. gcc usually does the right thing for the platform itself unless you are doing something very special.

Comment: Yes, gcc is fine. Anyway, the platform is a customized micro.

Comment: Olgac, the aligned attribute works really fine, thanks. Anyway it seems that there is no way to use the same alignment also for arrays inside structures. i.e. int16 a[4]: &a[0] = 0x00, &a[1]=0x02, &a[2]=0x08, &a[3]=0x0A..

Comment: C11 has [`_Alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) specifier

Comment: @myaut AFAIK it can only enforce more strict alignment, not make it more weak. Same with C++ `alignas`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: But it seems that OP ask for strictier alignment (if I correctly understand his example). See my answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C11 has [`_Alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) specifier. This declaration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct foo {
    _Alignas(8) int32_t a;
    _Alignas(4) int16_t b;
    _Alignas(4) int8_t c;
    _Alignas(8) int32_t d;
    _Alignas(8) int32_t e;
};

#define OFF(s, f)   ((uintptr_t)(&(s).f) - (uintptr_t)(&(s)))

int main() {
    char x;
    struct foo foo;

    printf("%p %x %x %x %x %x\n", (uintptr_t)(&foo), OFF(foo, a), OFF(foo, b), 
                                OFF(foo, c), OFF(foo, d), OFF(foo, e));
}
```

Gives exact alignments you ask for:

```
0x7fff6cbf2780 0 4 8 10 18
```

Compiled with gcc 4.8.3 with `-std=gnu11` on x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

this struct definition:

```
struct foo{
    int32 a,
    int16 b,
    int8 c,
    int32 d,
    int32 e
};
```

is padded per the following:

```
struct foo{  <-- aligned on a 32 bit address boundary by compiler
    int32 a, <-- +0 
    int16 b, <-- +4
    int8 c,  <-- +6
             <-- +7 (1 byte padding)
    int32 d, <-- +8
    int32 e  <-- +12  (not +16 as indicated in posted code)
};
```